# What's the "OBEY" Tux logo all about?

Tags: linux, graphics

There's a variant on the Tux logo I keep seeing; recognizably Tux's head sat above a red "OBEY" text.  [Examples](http://www.google.co.uk/search?num=10&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=567&q=obey%20linux&oq=obey%20linux).

It's striking, but what the heck does it actually *mean* ?

I've seen it mentioned as being based on the ["Obama 'hope' poster"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama_%22Hope%22_poster) (given even more credence by some of the results in the above link); and to me it seems vaguely reminiscent of RedHat's old "Shadowman" logo.

I'd be interested to know where this iconography first appeared and what it's about.

(I mean, why "OBEY" rather than something more obviously aligned with FOSS-ey values; is it supposed to be ironic, or a reference to rabid zealotry ?  I'm in the UK so I'm guessing there's some crucial cultural context I'm missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OBEY meme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andre_the_Giant_Has_a_Posse) is actually from "Andre the Giant Has a Posse." See link.

Comment: Thanks!  Fascinating!  The only single piece of that I had any awareness of was seeing "They Live" back in the late 80s.